# Why does ConcurrentQueue.Enqueue method not add a value?

Tags: c#, wpf, concurrent-collections

I define ConcurrentQueue as a ViewModel class field in my WPF MVVM application:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<AGC_DataRecordToSave> _agcAbsoluteDataRecordsToSaveBuf = new ConcurrentQueue<AGC_DataRecordToSave>();
```

Below is AGC_DataRecordToSave definition:

```
/// <summary>
/// Structure of record to write in CSV-file.
/// </summary>
public class AGC_DataRecordToSave
{
    #region Public Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Data;
    /// <summary>
    /// Time
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan Time;
    /// <summary>
    /// Measuring Ultrasonic Beam.
    /// </summary>
    public int MeasuringBeam;
    /// <summary>
    /// Direction.
    /// </summary>
    public string Direction;
    /// <summary>
    /// Value from outer device.
    /// </summary>
    public double Value;

    #endregion
}
```

Then in System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tick handler (in the same class) I do the following:

```
AGC_DataRecordToSave record = new AGC_DataRecordToSave();
record.Data = new DateTime(this._currentDate.Date.Ticks);
record.Time = this._currentDate.TimeOfDay;
record.MeasuringBeam = 1;
record.Direction = "P1AB";
record.Value = automaticGainControl;
this._agcAbsoluteDataRecordsToSaveBuf.Enqueue(record);
```

And _agcAbsoluteDataRecordsToSaveBuf remains empty (Count == 0). So ConcurrentQueue.Enqueue method doesn't add the value to the collection. *AGC_DataRecordToSave record* object is created and filled with the data successfully. I check it in debuger. Why the value is not added to collection? Why this situation has plase? Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Who dequeues items on this queue?

Comment: Method in same class. This method is inside parallel TPL Task.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the OP: *Who dequeues items on this queue?*, and OP answered: *Method in same class. This method is inside parallel TPL Task.*.

So for the time that you check queue's count, some of the parallel tasks have already dequeued the queued item!

Comment: Yes, really. Adding to the collection works in right way. Thank you.

Comment: @Prohor No problem ;)